# Can I gedit something in Mac's Terminal

Tags: macos, gedit

When I was using a Linux laptop as my dev machine, I used to do "gedit xxxx" in a Terminal. Now I just switched to MacBook, I d like to do the same thing.

I know that I can open gedit in a command line like "open gedit", but can I add the file name? Otherwise I have to use vim. I am not a fan of vim.

Comment: not a fan of vim!? blashpemy!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add

`alias gedit="open -a gedit"`

to `~/.bash_profile` :

Now you'll be able to gedit directly from the command line.

Comment: Not exactly the same, because in Linux you can do `gedit nonexisting_file`, whereas Mac's `open` will say file does not exist.

Answer (score 5):

try:

```
open -a /path/to/gedit /path/to/file.txt
```

Comment: just perfect... this should be way up

Answer (score 2):

I added the following to my PATH:

```
:~/Applications/gedit.app/Contents/MacOS/
```

and afterwards I was able to access gedit from 
the command line. One caveat: if gedit is not already running on the system, then it throws an error if I launch it from the command line. Once gedit is already running though, this works to open files in gedit from the command line.

To edit the path, open ~/.profile in an editor

Answer (score 0):

I use textmate for dev, here is a tutorial how it is done for Textmate

http://manual.macromates.com/en/using_textmate_from_terminal.html

I believe the same would apply to gedit.

Hope it helps